# Calculate Daily return using intraday prices?

Tags: r, return, time-series, xts

I have 1 min prices for each day begining 09:30 to 4:00pm and i need to calculate daily log return i.e. log(close price on the day / opening price on the day)? How to do this using R?

my data looks like

```
2014-02-03 09:30:00    10.450000
2014-02-03 09:31:00    10.450000
2014-02-03 09:32:00    10.326600
2014-02-03 09:33:00    10.290000
.
.
2014-02-03 04:00:00    10.326500
...
2014-07-31 09:30:00    15.8500
2014-07-31 09:31:00    15.8600
2014-07-31 09:32:00    15.8600
.
2014-07-31 03:50:00    15.9101
2014-07-31 04:00:00    15.9300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply.daily()`. Here's an example using `apply.monthly()` on daily data. The concept is the same.

```
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix[,"Close"])
apply.monthly(x, function(p) log(last(p)/as.numeric(first(p))))
                   [,1]
2007-01-31  0.002152642
2007-02-28  0.008169076
2007-03-31 -0.032065389
2007-04-30  0.009559690
2007-05-31 -0.035670840
2007-06-30  0.002430626
```

You need the `as.numeric()` call because arithmetic operations on xts/zoo objects always align by the index first. `as.numeric()` removes the index.